# How do i see the size of my trash in iPhoto '11?

Tags: snow-leopard, photos.app

I'm just curious how much space I'll retrieve by deleting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that easy since iPhoto uses a database to track the files. When you trash the file, it simply removes the reference to that photo in whatever events and albums it used to be included.

It makes a reference to the original and modified files, so they don't actually get moved into a folder that you can get a quick estimate on the total trash size.

These pointers to a photo are so small that they are a rounding error compared even to the size of a small thumbnail of your photo.

The best way is to just get an estimate how large the typical picture you take is and see how much space a thousand of them take. You'll then be able to know if emptying the trash has any chance on making a difference size wise.

Comment: I'm quite sure this feature was in iPhoto '08, I think I'd just select all the photos and command-i to bring up the info pane. I might be wrong though. Thanks for the answer (I think the trash is around 12000 photos, taken with various cameras).

Comment: I think you are right about older versions. They were slower for a reason - this database storage is a big reason why.